# Automatically create screen sessions to run tasks in parallel

Tags: scripts, screen

Is it possible to write a script that automatically create screen sessions (e.g. create all 10 screen sessions) so that each of these sessions will run its own task?

Currently I have to use `screen -S session1` → run something → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get out and `screen -S session2` ...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to run scripts `task1`, `task2`, ..., `task10`, located in the current directory, in corresponding `screen` sessions `session1`, `session2`, ..., `session10`. Suppose further that, when each task ends, you want its session to continue with an interactive shell, so you will still be able to attach to it, view the task's output in it, and run further commands in it.

```bash
for i in {1..10}; do
    screen -dmS "session$i" sh -c "./task$i; exec bash"
done
```

This is the method [**jw013 describes there**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47279/11938), but done repeatedly in a loop. Each session starts detached (`-dm`) and uses `sh -c` to run a script, then replaces itself with `bash`.

In the manual method you've been using, each session starts attached, and you detach from each one (except possibly the last) in order to create those that remain. But with the method shown here, nothing is attached yet, even though the scripts are all running. You can manage and attach to the sessions in the usual way. For example, `screen -ls` will list all of them, and `screen -x session10` attaches to `session10`, the session running `task10`.

If you want each session to end immediately after the script runs (which is dissimilar to the results of what you're currently doing manually) then you can use just `"./task$i"` instead of `sh -c "./task$i; exec bash"`:

```bash
for i in {1..10}; do
    screen -dmS "session$i" "./task$i"
done
```

Whichever way you use, you can run the whole `for` loop, as written, however you like: as a command in an interactive shell, or in a script, or in a shell function. The loop itself finishes almost immediately; no matter how long your tasks take to run, the loop completes once all the `screen` sessions are started.